# How to create a recursive components with add edit and delete function in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want to create a category list with each one having a sub-category. and it should be added, edit and delete

As an example

```
 - Breakfast > Egg Types > Some of name
 - Lunch > Chicken > Some of name
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your question, consider to edit it and provide more information like how is your object structure?, Are you using an UI framework? Provide an UI example of what do you want to do.

Comment: Hi @NicolasLucero my object like this

{
        "Main Category": [
          {
            "name": "Sub Category",
            "subData": {
              "Inner Sub Category": [
                {
                  "name": "Inner Sub Category Value",
                  "subData": {}
                },
              ]
            }
        }]
}

like so, currently i'm not using any UI framework

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had experience with a similar case. Only I had comments
I should you to create a Component which the take as props array with items. I recommend taking the following structure of menu item

```js
{
id:1,
   text:"All",
  subItems:[{
    id:67,
    text:"Sub",
    subItems:[{
    id:98,
    text:"Sub of Sub"
    }]
  }]
}
```

This is my final answer

```js
import {useState} from "react";

const Menu=({propsItems}:{propsItems})=>{
    const [items,setItems]=useState(propsItems);
    const deleteItemHandle=(id)=>{
        setItems(prevState =>prevState.filter(item=>item.id!==id) )
    }
    const [inputValue,setInputValue]=useState("")
    const [editValue,setEditValue]=useState("")
    const [isEditMode,setIsEditMode]=useState(false);
    const addItemHandle=()=>{
        if (inputValue.trim()){
            setItems(prevState =>[...prevState,{id:Math.random(),text:inputValue,subItems:[]}] )
            setInputValue("")
        }
    }
    const editItemHandle=(id:number)=>{
        if (editValue){
            setItems(prevState =>prevState.map(item=>{
                if (item.id===id){
                    return {...item,text:editValue}
                }
                return item
            }) )
            setIsEditMode(false)
            setEditValue("")
        }
    }
    const toggleEditMode=()=>setIsEditMode(true)
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {items.map(item=>{
                    return <li key={item.id}>
                         <span>
                             {isEditMode ? <div>
                                 <input onChange={(e:any)=>setEditValue(e.target.value)} value={editValue} type="text"/>
                                 <button onClick={()=>editItemHandle(item.id)}  >Edit</button>
                             </div>:  <span onDoubleClick={toggleEditMode}>
                               {item.text}
                           </span>}
                             <span onClick={()=>deleteItemHandle(item.id)}
                                   style={{color:"red"}}>X
                        </span>
                        {item.subItems?.length ? <Menu propsItems={item.subItems}/>:"" }
                             {!item.subItems.length && <div>
                                 <input value={inputValue} onChange={(e)=>setInputValue(e.target.value)}
                                        type="text" placeholder={"Add item"}/>
                                 <button onClick={addItemHandle}>Add Item</button>
                             </div>  }
                        </span>
                    </li>
                })}
            </ul>
            <div>
                <input value={inputValue} onChange={(e)=>setInputValue(e.target.value)}
                       type="text" placeholder={"Add item"}/>
                       <button onClick={addItemHandle}>Add Item</button>
            </div>


        </div>
    )
}
export default Menu
```